# pass a data to next page with dynamic routing in next Js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next Js 13 app i'm using dynamic routing. and in the first screen i'm fetching the data from server and storing it in an array. so whenever the user selects an item it will redirect them to a detail page. so my question is how can i pass the selected item list to the next page along with dynamic routing?

home page

```
 {house.images.map((img, index) => {
          return (
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: `/living/${house.id}`,
                query: { house: house },
              }}
              key={index}
            >
              <div
                key={index}
                className=" w-full relative -z-10 pt-[100%] cursor-pointer"
              >
                <Image
                  src={img}
                  alt="profile"
                  fill
                  className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 -z-10 object-cover rounded-2xl ease-in-out duration-200"
                />
              </div>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
```

and detail page

```
function DetailPage({ params: { homeid } }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { house } = router.query;
  //... the rest of the code
}
```

and this displays an error b/c i'm using `next/router`.

Comment: As it is SSR, you could only pass the id as you do and fetch the item by the id, no?

Comment: @OneQ yes, i can only pass the id. is there a way i can pass in other params?

Comment: You can pass anything as a string but what do you want to pass ?

Comment: @OneQ i want to pass a list, this list consists of array of images, title, desc, referals, ... and much more. so i can't fit this inside of the url

Comment: Why can't you fetch all of those with the id ?

Comment: @OneQ b/c i want to make the routing fast. so this way there won't be any loading time, b/c it will fetch the data before hand

Comment: @OneQ also i'm using firebase so i want to minimize the cost

Comment: Store it in the js cookies and get it from there but every time you fetch data at server side don't forget to update the cookies.